# Sorted Insertion in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function that does sorted insertion based on two variables, `level` and `name`. Apparently I'm having some logic and syntax errors.

My linked list structure:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int level;
    char name;
};
```

My string compare function:

```
int compare(struct node *one, struct node *two)
{
    return strcmp(one->name, two->name);
}
```

My insertion function:

```
void insert(struct node **head, const int level, const char name, int(*cmp)(struct node *l, struct node *r))
{
    struct node *new =NULL;
    /* Find the insertion point */
    for (; *head; head = &(*head)->next)
    {
        if ((*head)->level > level) {     // I think this is what is causing the issue
            if (compare(*head, new) > 0)
            break;
        }
    }

    new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->level = level;
    new->name = name;
    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
```

and this is the call stack:

```
insert(node **head, const int level, const char name, int(*)(node *, node *))
```

Comment: When saying you have an error, it's generally beneficial to include said error.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I have included the error in the end.

Comment: BTW: you are using a C++ compiler to compile C code. (and the code should *not* compile, since you use `new` as an identifier)

Comment: @wildplasser I did fix that. but it seems to be a logic issue. the code is compiling fine.

Comment: BTW it is not appropiate to correct the errors in your question, it makes the answers look like nonsense, which they are not.

Comment: @wildplasser reverted it back. thanks for the heads up

Comment: Oh, and you checked the wrong answer. Did you even read it?

Comment: Now that you have corrected the error with `new`, you should post a new question with describing the most recent behavior. Also tell us what steps you have taken to try to debug the problem.

Comment: they are both pointing out the same issue. that's why I went with the one which had the more clarity for others who will read the answers later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax error is this line:

```
return strcmp(one->name, two->name);
```

The function `strcmp` expect two `char*` (aka char pointers) but you give it two `char`.

The problem is... Do you want

```
char name;
```

or

```
char* name;
```

That is important in order to get `compare` right.

Further you need to rearrange your `insert` function so that you create the new node before using it. Something like:

```
void insert(struct node **head, const int level, const char name, int(*cmp)(struct node *l, struct node *r))
{
    struct node *new =NULL;

    // Create and initialize new....
    new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->level = level;
    new->name = name;

    /* Find the insertion point */
    for (; *head; head = &(*head)->next)
    {
        if ((*head)->level > level) {     // I think this is what is causing the issue
            if (cmp(*head, new) > 0)
                        // ^^^ So that you can use it here

            break;
        }
    }

    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
```

Comment: you are completely right. though I'm still having trouble with the logic. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a *NULL* value to the **cmp** function (?!? probably the correct function is **int compare(...)**. Try to initialize the value of the *new* variable before to pass it to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `node.name` to be of type `char`, but your comparison function is written as if they were null-terminated arrays of `char` or pointers into such arrays (i.e. C strings).  You appear to want this:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int level;
    char *name;
};
```

or maybe this:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int level;
    char name[MY_MAXIMUM_NAME_LENGTH_PLUS_ONE];
};
```

Furthermore, your `insert()` function passes a NULL pointer to the comparison function as its second argument, because you never allocate any memory for pointer `new`, and, of course, never assign values to the non-existent members.  That doesn't even make sense.  What do you think you're comparing to?  You seem to want something like this:

```
struct node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);

if (!new) {
    // allocation failure -- abort ...
}

new->level = level;
new->name = /* hmmmm ... */;
```

Of course, the problem with the type of your names crops up here, too.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have updated the code but the error remains the same. I have updated the post.

Comment: @pouria, you need to set the values of the members of `*new` *before* you pass it to the comparison function.  Otherwise, what do you think you're comparing to?

Comment: you are right. I just fixed the syntax issue .but apparently I'm having trouble with logic as well